# Excel 2013 Windows Class Names

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

Have to learn a little API for my VBA project so am experimenting. The interwebs suggests this code should work in a sub to find a windowshandle

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName    As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Public Sub Test()
Dim P As String
P = Windows(1).Caption
MsgBox P
MsgBox FindWindowA("", P)
End Sub
```

With a sheet open with caption "Book1.xlsm" when I run this code I get 
"Book1.xlsm" but then "0"

What am I doing wrong? If I try "EXCEL7" as a class name instead of the null string, I get the same thing.

Thanks to those older and wiser

Added later after discussion below....
This isn't really an answer to my question as it's not clear on the face of it why windows can't be found via FindWindowA (that's what it claims to do, as I read it) but further research suggests that I can't get the window handles directly via FindWindowA, but have to take into account that they might be child windows. So this code at least find my window handle:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow _
Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) _
As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx _
Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd1 As Long, _
        ByVal hWnd2 As Long, _
        ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
        ByVal lpsz2 As String) _
 As Long
Dim hWndParent As Long, hWndDskTop As Long, hWndChild As Long, hWndMine As        Long
Sub Test()
hWndParent = FindWindow("XLMAIN", vbNullString)
hWndDskTop = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
hWndMine = FindWindowEx(hWndDskTop, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
MsgBox hWndMine
```

That is finding the window handle of Book1.xlsm as I originally wanted.

Comment: Your version of Windows and Office, are they 32-bit or 64-bit? Also perhaps try using "XLMAIN" as the class

Comment: 64 bit windows, 32 bit office

Comment: You shouldn't be using the 64-bit *PtrSafe* version of FindWindowA with 32-bit Office. Use the 32-bit version or use compiler directives so that the workbook and VBA project will work on both 32-bit and 64-bit Office installations.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you are going to omit the lpClassName on the call to [FindWindowA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you need to pass it a null pointer.  Try this:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim P As String
    P = Windows(1).Caption
    MsgBox P
    MsgBox FindWindowA(vbNullString, P)
End Sub
```

This is actually a perfect example of why you should use vbNullString instead of "" to signify an empty string.  When you use "", the compiler actually constructs a String with zero length and assigns a pointer to it.  When you use vbNullString, you get a generic null String pointer.  This code demonstrates:

```
Public Sub StringAddresses()

    MsgBox StrPtr("")
    MsgBox StrPtr(vbNullString)

End Sub
```

**Edit:** This was bothering me, so I did a bit of digging and found the class name for the MDI windows that Excel uses.  This code should return the first Window registered in that class.  Note that if there is more than one window open, this might not give you the one you are after:

```
Public Sub Test()

    MsgBox FindWindowA("MS-SDIb", vbNullString)

End Sub
```

**Edit 2:**  Don't know why it took so long for this to occur to me - if it doesn't find your caption, set it to your search term (:facepalm:).

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim hWnd As Long, cache As String

    cache = Windows(1).Caption
    Windows(1).Caption = "FindME!"
    hWnd = FindWindowA(vbNullString, "FindME!")
    Windows(1).Caption = cache
    Debug.Print hWnd

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. Reports "0" as well

Comment: Ok, so at least I'm not crazy. Using ActiveWorkBook.Name (as you have it) still returns nothing. Is there something to the 32 bit Excel 64 bit windows situation? I've tried this without the PtrSafe with the same result

Comment: @user3486991 - No, this shouldn't have anything to do with 32/64bit.  The issue is that the Windows(1).Caption doesn't match with any of the strings that GetWindowText is returning (FindWindow uses the GetWindowText API to check against the value you pass in lpWindowName). The 0 return value from FindWindow is a successful call, but no window was found with a matching title.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to try that. Note that I've edited the original post with something I found that now gets me the handle, although I'm still not clear on the concepts.

Comment: @user3486991 - The edit you posted just walks down the hierarchy of parent and child windows. The first one gets you the main Excel window, then the second call gets you a child window in "XLDESK", and the last one gets you an "EXCEL7" window that's a child of the second one.  Keep in mind that at each step there can be multiple matches and the FindWindowEx only gives you the first one, and EXCEL7 includes all loaded plugins.  I'm still curious how your hWnds are getting registered with different caption text.

Comment: @userComintern Thanks for that. Still getting no window handles off of that though!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the 64-bit *PtrSafe* version of FindWindowA with 32-bit Office. Use the 32-bit version or use compiler directives so that the workbook and VBA project will work on both 32-bit and 64-bit Office installations.

```
#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
```

That compiles but I have not tested the operation.

**Addendum:**

Just tested and this works on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems:

```
Debug.Print FindWindow("Notepad", vbNullString)   ' works OK when Notepad is open
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can confirm that the declarations and the code  as you have

Comment: it work on my system, but I'm still getting 0 when trying to get the windows handle of an excel window: same code as above returns 0

Comment: @Jeeped - PtrSafe works fine in both 32-bit and 64-bit Office, as does LongPtr. It doesn't work in versions before VBA7 though.  The preprocessor constant was added to determine which declaration syntax to use because the two keywords don't exist in prior versions - [more information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278832.aspx)

Comment: same issue as @user3486991 , for excel Debug.Print FindWindow("excel", vbNullString) or Debug.Print FindWindow("*excel*", vbNullString)

Answer (score -1):

Gives output like this

```
Order   Level   WindowText  ClassName   HWnd    ParentHWnd  ProcessID   ParentProcessID ThreadID    ModuleNameHWin  EXENameProcess
1   0   «No Window Text 0»  msvb_lib_tooltips   67334   67334   3000    2616    3592    C:\Windows\system32\MSCOMCTL.OCX    Ed.exe
2   0   «No Window Text 0»  msvb_lib_tooltips   67332   67334   3000    2616    3592    C:\Windows\system32\MSCOMCTL.OCX    Ed.exe
3   0   «No Window Text 0»  msvb_lib_tooltips   67330   67334   3000    2616    3592    C:\Windows\system32\MSCOMCTL.OCX    Ed.exe
4   0   «No Window Text 0»  msvb_lib_tooltips   67328   67334   3000    2616    3592    C:\Windows\system32\MSCOMCTL.OCX    Ed.exe
5   0   «No Window Text 0»  tooltips_class32    4195002 67334   2616    508 1924    C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_
```

Level is the number of tabs to see the relationship between parent/child window.

```
1   0   «No Window Text 0»  msvb_lib_tooltips   
2   1   «No Window Text 0»
```

means

```
1   0   «No Window Text 0»  msvb_lib_tooltips   
    2   1   «No Window Text 0»
```

showing line 2 is a child of line 1

I replaced the insert into a RTF control using TOM with MsgBox.

```
Public Declare Function GetTopWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetWindowModuleFileName Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowModuleFileNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal WinModule As String, StringLength As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
'    Public Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
          Private Declare Function Process32Next Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
          Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal Handle As Long) As Long
          Private Declare Function Process32First Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
         Private Declare Function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal th32ProcessID As Long) As Long
         Private Type PROCESSENTRY32
             dwSize As Long
             cntUsage As Long
             th32ProcessID As Long           ' This process
             th32DefaultHeapID As Long
             th32ModuleID As Long            ' Associated exe
             cntThreads As Long
             th32ParentProcessID As Long     ' This process's parent process
             pcPriClassBase As Long          ' Base priority of process threads
             dwFlags As Long
             szExeFile As String * 260 ' MAX_PATH
          End Type

          Private Type OSVERSIONINFO
             dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
             dwMajorVersion As Long
             dwMinorVersion As Long
             dwBuildNumber As Long
             dwPlatformId As Long           '1 = Windows 95 2 = Windows NT
             szCSDVersion As String * 128
          End Type

           Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 1024
           Private Const PROCESS_VM_READ = 16
           Private Const MAX_PATH = 260
           Private Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = &HF0000
           Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
          'STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED Or SYNCHRONIZE Or &HFFF
           Private Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF
           Private Const TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = &H2&
           Private Const hNull = 0
           Private Const GW_CHILD = 5
           Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2





    Sub Main()
    '    WindowChain = 0
        Dim hwnd As Long
            hwnd = GetTopWindow(0)
            If hwnd <> 0 Then
                AddChildWindows hwnd, 0
            End If
    End Sub

    Private Function AddChildWindows(ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal Level As Long) As String
          Dim gwfnhwnd As Long, X As Long, WT As String, CN As String, Length As Long, hwnd As Long, TID As Long, PID As Long, MN As String, Ret As Long, Parenthwnd As Long
            Static Order As Long
            Static FirstTime As Long
            Parenthwnd = hwndParent
            If Level = 0 Then
                            hwnd = hwndParent
            Else
                hwnd = GetWindow(hwndParent, GW_CHILD)
            End If
            Do While hwnd <> 0
                     WT = Space(512)
                      Length = GetWindowText(hwnd, WT, 508)
                      WT = Left$(WT, Length)
                      If WT = "" Then WT = Chr(171) & "No Window Text " & Err.LastDllError & Chr(187)
                      CN = Space(512)
                      Length = GetClassName(hwnd, CN, 508)
                      CN = Left$(CN, Length)
                      If CN = "" Then CN = "Error=" & Err.LastDllError


                      TID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, PID)

                      MN = Space(512)
                      Length = GetWindowModuleFileName(hwnd, MN, 508)
                      If Length = 0 Then
                        MN = Chr(171) & "Not Available Error=" & Err.LastDllError & Chr(187)
                      Else
                        MN = Left$(MN, Length)
                      End If


                     Dim f As Long, sname As String, PList As String, PPID As Long
                     Dim hSnap As Long, proc As PROCESSENTRY32, Temp As String
                     hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)
                     If hSnap = hNull Then Exit Function
                     proc.dwSize = LenB(proc)
                     ' Iterate through the processes
                     f = Process32First(hSnap, proc)
                     Do
                            If PID = proc.th32ProcessID Then
                                sname = StrZToStr(proc.szExeFile)
                                PPID = proc.th32ParentProcessID
                            End If
                            f = Process32Next(hSnap, proc)
                     Loop While f = 1
                      Order = Order + 1
    '                  CStr(Order) & " HWnd=" & FormatNumber$(hwnd, 0, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbFalse) & " Parent HWnd=" & FormatNumber$(Parenthwnd, 0, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbFalse) & " Level=" & CStr(Level) & WT & " (" & CN & ")" & " PID=" & FormatNumber$(PID, 0, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbFalse) & " TID=" & FormatNumber$(TID, 0, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbFalse) & " Module Name:" & MN & " ExeName:" & sname & vbCrLf
                    If FirstTime = 0 Then
                        MsgBox vbCrLf & "Order" & vbTab & "Level" & vbTab & "WindowText" & vbTab & "ClassName" & vbTab & "HWnd" & vbTab & "ParentHWnd" & vbTab & "ProcessID" & vbTab & "ParentProcessID" & vbTab & "ThreadID" & vbTab & "ModuleNameHWin" & vbTab & "EXENameProcess"
                        FirstTime = 1
                    End If
                    MsgBox vbCrLf & CStr(Order) & vbTab & CStr(Level) & vbTab & WT & vbTab & CN & vbTab & CStr(hwnd) & vbTab & CStr(Parenthwnd) & vbTab & CStr(PID) & vbTab & CStr(PPID) & vbTab & CStr(TID) & vbTab & MN & vbTab & sname

                      AddChildWindows hwnd, Level + 1
                      hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)
            Loop
          End Function



     Function StrZToStr(S As String) As String
         StrZToStr = Left$(S, Len(S) - 1)
      End Function
```

Comment: Not sure how this solves the OP's issue, but you should probably replace the MsgBox output with Debug.Print.  Luckily I noticed it before I tried the code and didn't have to dismiss over 1300 message boxes - and I only had 9 top level windows open.