# Find out if excel is running

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find out if excel is running, because after i am done creating excel files I need to know if I should close down excel or not.

My method is working fine for me, but it fails on another user and I have no idea why it is failing. My bet would be that the while loop runs forever. So should I add a counter to avoid this or is there a better way to find out if excel is running?

```
Function ListWins(Optional title = "*", Optional Class = "*") As Boolean
    Dim hWndThis As Long
    ListWins = True
    hWndThis = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    While hWndThis
        Dim sTitle As String, sClass As String
        sTitle = Space$(255)
        sTitle = Left$(sTitle, GetWindowText(hWndThis, sTitle, Len(sTitle)))
        sClass = Space$(255)
        sClass = Left$(sClass, GetClassName(hWndThis, sClass, Len(sClass)))
        If sTitle Like title And sClass Like Class Then
            ListWins = False
            Debug.Print sTitle, sClass
        End If
        hWndThis = GetWindow(hWndThis, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Those Win32 (User32...?) API calls have to be imported differently for 32-bit and 64-bit Office installations. Perhaps that explains the difference between the two computers. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723694/excel-2013-windows-class-names/29724663#29724663).

Comment: Thanks, we both run 32bit version of word but he uses 32 bit pc and I use 64bit pc.

Comment: Just FWIW: You can use GetObject(, "Excel.Application") and if that errors (429, as I recall) it's not running.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the new function that works for me:

```
#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If

Function ExcelOpen() As Boolean
    ExcelOpen = FindWindow("XLMAIN", vbNullString)
End Function
```